# Log4Net exception while writing exception to MySQL database

Tags: c#, mysql, database, logging, log4net

When logging an exception, it is correctly shown in the command line. However, it does not write to the database. The other parameters are logged correctly.

In my `app.config`, the exception is configured as follows:

```
<commandText value="INSERT INTO logs (time, log_level, logger, message, exception, thread) VALUES (?time, ?log_level, ?logger, ?message, ?exception, ?thread)" />
```

Parameter:

```
<parameter>
    <parameterName value="exception" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="2000" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%exception" />
    </layout>
</parameter>
```

I am testing with:

```
try
{
    throw new DivideByZeroException();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    log.Error("", e);
}
```

I enabled Log4Net debugging and got the following output:

```
log4net: Hierarchy Threshold []
A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
log4net:ERROR [CustomAdoNetAppender] ErrorCode: GenericFailure. Exception while writing to database
12:25:37,902 [Game.Program] {exceptions} () ERROR:  System.DivideByZeroException: Attempted to divide by zero.
   at Game.Program.Init() in --:line 98

log4net:ERROR [CustomAdoNetAppender] ErrorCode: GenericFailure. Exception while writing to database
System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
   at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
   at System.String.System.IConvertible.ToInt32(IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.Convert.ToInt32(Object value)
   at MySql.Data.Types.MySqlInt32.MySql.Data.Types.IMySqlValue.WriteValue(MySqlPacket packet, Boolean binary, Object val, Int32 length)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter.Serialize(MySqlPacket packet, Boolean binary, MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Statement.SerialiSystem.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
   at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
   at System.String.System.IConvertible.ToInt32(IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.Convert.ToInt32(Object value)
   at MySql.Data.Types.MySqlInt32.MySql.Data.Types.IMySqlValue.WriteValue(MySqlPacket packet, Boolean binary, Object val, Int32 length)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter.Serialize(MySqlPacket packet, Boolean binary, MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Statement.SerializeParameter(MySqlParameterCollection parameters, MySqlPacket packet, String parmName, Int32 parameterIndex)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Statement.InternalBindParameters(String sql, MySqlParameterCollection parameters, MySqlPacket packet)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Statement.BindParameters()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Statement.Execute()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.PreparableStatement.Execute()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender.SendBuffer(IDbTransaction dbTran, LoggingEvent[] events)
   at log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender.SendBuffer(LoggingEvent[] events)
zeParameter(MySqlParameterCollection parameters, MySqlPacket packet, String parmName, Int32 parameterIndex)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Statement.InternalBindParameters(String sql, MySqlParameterCollection parameters, MySqlPacket packet)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Statement.BindParameters()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Statement.Execute()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.PreparableStatement.Execute()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender.SendBuffer(IDbTransaction dbTran, LoggingEvent[] events)
   at log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender.SendBuffer(LoggingEvent[] events)
```

Comment: Seems like an issue with a value you're trying to insert. I think you have a column of NUMBER type. Can you post the value you're trying to insert for the column. Or better, values for all bind variables.

Comment: Asking more directly, what are values of ?time, ?log_level, ?logger, ?message, ?exception, ?thread variables?

Comment: These are all internal values of Log4Net. They are logged correctly to the database except for exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error.

Apparently, I added some global variables which were not initialized yet when calling my test exception function. I initialized these variables to empty strings and zeroes and it worked.

Comment: which variables ?